# Select values in a column based on multiple rows in a different column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with sales orders that have multiple products (original dataframe below). I need create a second dataframe showing the sales orders, whether the sales order has only one product or not (standalone), and the name of the product. Any help on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks gang!

Original dataframe:

```html
<table><tbody>
  <tr><th> </th><th>A</th><th>B</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>Sales Order</td><td>Product</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>1111</td><td>Software</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td><td>1111</td><td>Support</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td><td>2222</td><td>Hardware</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td><td>3333</td><td>Software</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td><td>4444</td><td>Hardware</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td><td>4444</td><td>Software</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Desired Output:

```html
<table><tbody>
  <tr><th> </th><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>Sales Order</td><td>Standalone</td><td>Product (SA)</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>1111</td><td>No</td><td>Not SA</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td><td>2222</td><td>Yes</td><td>Hardware</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td><td>3333</td><td>Yes</td><td>Software</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td><td>4444</td><td>No</td><td>Not SA</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

- SA stands for Standalone

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried to accomplish this? What problems have you faced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your starting DataFrame looks like:

```
  Sales Order   Product
0        1111  Software
1        1111   Support
2        2222  Hardware
3        3333  Software
4        4444  Hardware
5        4444  Software
```

First [create a new DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) to hold your results.

```
res = pd.DataFrame(index=df['Sales Order'].unique(), columns=['Standalone', 'Product'])
```

Then populate it. This can be done in several ways. Below is a method using [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

```
for sales_order, dft in df.groupby('Sales Order'):
    standalone = 'Yes' if len(dft) == 1 else 'No'
    product = dft.iloc[0, 1] if len(dft) == 1 else 'Not SA'
    res.loc[sales_order] = [standalone, product]
```